# Prove that every acyclic graph has at least one source vertex and at least one termination vertex

Tags: algorithms, random-graphs

How can i prove that every acyclic graph has at least one source vertex and one(at least) termination vertex?

Comment: I take it that your book does not allow an empty graph, nor an infinite one?

Comment: Just walk around the graph.

Comment: @Michael I would say using case distinction as a better advice than walking around the graph

Comment: I don't know what "case distinction" means here.  The key idea here is to just walk until you cannot walk.  This is shown in the more detailed answer below that argues "Walk around your graph..."

Answer (score 11):

Suppose not.  Then either, your graph has no sources or your graph has no sinks.  Let's assume for a minute that it has no sinks.  Pick a random vertex as a starting point.  Walk around your graph following directed edges.  There are no sinks, so you can always continue walking.  But you are in a finite graph, so the pigeonhole principle says you will eventually hit the same vertex twice.  That means you walked in a cycle, which is a contradiction.

If there are no sources, then replace your graph with a new one where you give every edge the opposite orientation.  Now you have a graph with no sinks.  The above argument gives a cycle in that graph.  If you turn all the edges back around, you still have a cycle.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is: that P=(u,…v)  is the maximum path of the graph D.If a vertex u is adjacent to one vertex of P, then i have a cyrcle. So its wrong. If vertex u is adjacent to one vertex which dont belong to P, then i have a new bigger path. So the vertex is not neighboring an other vertex and d(u) = 0